# Boot windows from moved internal to external HDD

Tags: windows-7, boot, external-hard-drive

I moved my internal hard disk which have windows 7 installation on it . I'm using it as an external hard disk now . I want to boot from it but when I try to do this I face the blue error screen which stop the booting process and restarts .

When I use it as internal it boots normally ?
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you physically move the hard drive itself, or did you just clone (or worse, copy&paste?) If you physically moved the hard drive from the laptop to an external casing... this might sound weird, but there's a chance it might be the wrong USB port. I was installing an OS on a clean computer (no OS) and the computer wouldn't boot from the install USB flash unless it was plugged into a certain USB port. Turns out it was because those USB ports didn't run properly without the driver for them installed, which it of course didn't have because there was no OS. So try every USB port your computer has. In any case, it can be difficult to diagnose the problem without knowing the exact error message from the bluescreen -- try writing it down and searching it online, it might shed some light on the nature of the problem.

If you did not physically move the hard drive, and just copied/pasted the contents onto another drive (or something similar), that's probably the problem. There's more to booting from a hard drive than just moving the files over (I tried it once out of curiosity, as expected it didn't work and just gave an error). You'd need special disk-cloning software (of which there are many) to properly clone the disk. Otherwise, if worst comes to worst, there's always the option of backing up your files, re(?)-installing the OS onto the external drive, then moving your files back over to it, but that's a bit of an extreme option.